fix CORS in my aws api getway with lambda function
I am trying to send requests from my web app to my api getway but get CORS error:
'has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'
even though I enabled CORS in the getway proxy settings, and added the code like they described in the docs (when using proxy it is neaded to add the headers through the code itself), this is the code:
const app = require("./app"); // Express app
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
require("dotenv").config();
const MongoDB = require("./app/db/mongodb");

let isDbConnected = false;

const connectToDatabase = async () => {
  if (!isDbConnected) {
    await MongoDB.instance().connect();
    isDbConnected = true;
  }
};

// Lambda handler
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase(); // Ensure the database is connected before handling the request

    const handler = serverless(app); // Wrap your Express app
    const response = await handler(event, context); // Delegate the request to the Express app

    // Add CORS headers to the response
    response.headers = {
      ...response.headers,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Allow all origins
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*", // Allow all methods
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", // Allow all headers
    };

    return response; // Return the modified response
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to process request: ", err);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Internal Server Error" }),
    };
  }
};

in my api getway it looks like this:


someone please help!
I tried send requsts fo the api getway and expected response wth proper headers but got CORS error

notice the OPTIONS endpoint. This is used in what's called a Preflight request, and should probably be adjusted to fit your use case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
